# Pandas: Find the max value in one column containing lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
fly_frame:
          day    plcae
0  [1,2,3,4,5]       A
1    [1,2,3,4]       B
2        [1,2]       C
3     [1,2,3,4]      D
```

If I want to find the max value in each entry in the day column.

For example:

```
fly_frame:
          day    plcae
0           5       A
1           4       B
2           2       C
3           4       D
```

What should I do?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
df.day.apply(max)
#0    5
#1    4
#2    2
#3    4
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with `max`:

```
#if strings

#import ast

#print (type(df.loc[0, 'day']))
#<class 'str'>

#df['day'] = df['day'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

---

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'day']))
<class 'list'>

df['day'] = df['day'].apply(max)
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df['day'] = [max(x) for x in df['day']]
```

---

```
print (df)
   day plcae
0    5     A
1    4     B
2    2     C
3    4     D
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest bringing your dataframe into a better format first.

```
>>> df
               day plcae
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]     A
1     [1, 2, 3, 4]     B
2           [1, 2]     C
3     [1, 2, 3, 4]     D
>>> 
>>> df = pd.concat([df.pop('day').apply(pd.Series), df], axis=1)
>>> df
     0    1    2    3    4 plcae
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0     A
1  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN     B
2  1.0  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN     C
3  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN     D
```

Now everything is easier, for example computing the maximum of numeric values along the columns.

```
>>> df.max(axis=1)
0    5.0
1    4.0
2    2.0
3    4.0
dtype: float64
```

edit: renaming the index might also be useful to you.

```
>>> df.max(axis=1).rename(df['plcae'])
A    5.0
B    4.0
C    2.0
D    4.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a combination of [pd.concat()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [df.apply()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


fly_frame = pd.DataFrame({'day':[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4],[1,2],[1,2,3,4]],'place':['A','B','C','D']})

df = pd.concat([fly_frame['day'].apply(max),fly_frame.drop('day',axis=1)],axis=1)

print(df)



   day place
0    5     A
1    4     B
2    2     C
3    4     D
```

**Edit**
You can also use [df.join()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join) with:

```
fly_frame.drop('day',axis=1).join(fly_frame['day'].apply(np.max,axis=0))


place  day
0     A    5
1     B    4
2     C    2
3     D    4
```